# HttpHeaders - Authorization - username:password - Dont Work

Tags: angular

I have a problem with the Headers - If the password is a blank, should it go like this?
There will be another way to do it because that is not working for me

Thank you so much

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

getUsers() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('Usermame' + ':' + ''));

    this.http.get(this.url, { headers })
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data),
            err => console.log(err)
        );
}
```

I have an error in my code?

This is the result

Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: 168.63.53.239:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,x-goog-authuser
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

Comment: In Basic Auth in postman works perfect and brings me all the data

Comment: Can you send the auth token you put on postman?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this actually occurs because of the preflight request that Angular sends.  CORS needs to be enabled on the server API.  You can read about CORS at the link below...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am using chrome plugins Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: I believe that the error is originating from the API server.  I believe you will also need to set up CORS on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a Solution**

```
getUsers() {
    const url = 'Your URL';

    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username' + ':' + 'password'));

    return this.http.get(url, {headers});
}
```

*HttpHeaders class represents the header configuration options for an HTTP request. Instances should be assumed INMUTABLE with lazy parsing.*